# Minecraft 1.8 or above crashes when launching

Tags: minecraft

So, whenever I open Mc 1.8 or 1.12 (1.13 or 1.14 work just fine) it crashes, this is the log that I get

```
[18:47:22] [Client thread/INFO]: Setting user: zSnails
[18:47:22] [Client thread/INFO]: (Session ID is token:8198925bef7e4f9d8e75e6609e549bbb:7a5098d449394ed69b72c617c18bdc43)
[18:47:24] [Client thread/WARN]: Skipping bad option: key_key.attack:key.mouse.left
[18:47:24] [Client thread/WARN]: Skipping bad option: key_key.use:key.mouse.right
[18:47:24] [Client thread/WARN]: Skipping bad option: key_key.forward:key.keyboard.w
[18:47:24] [Client thread/WARN]: Skipping bad option: key_key.left:key.keyboard.a
[18:47:24] [Client thread/WARN]: Skipping bad option: key_key.back:key.keyboard.s
[18:47:24] [Client thread/WARN]: Skipping bad option: key_key.right:key.keyboard.d
[18:47:24] [Client thread/WARN]: Skipping bad option: key_key.jump:key.keyboard.space
[18:47:24] [Client thread/WARN]: Skipping bad option: key_key.sneak:key.keyboard.left.shift
[18:47:24] [Client thread/WARN]: Skipping bad option: key_key.sprint:key.keyboard.left.control
[18:47:24] [Client thread/WARN]: Skipping bad option: key_key.drop:key.keyboard.q
[18:47:24] [Client thread/WARN]: Skipping bad option: key_key.inventory:key.keyboard.e
[18:47:24] [Client thread/WARN]: Skipping bad option: key_key.chat:key.keyboard.t
[18:47:24] [Client thread/WARN]: Skipping bad option: key_key.playerlist:key.keyboard.tab
[18:47:24] [Client thread/WARN]: Skipping bad option: key_key.pickItem:key.mouse.middle
[18:47:24] [Client thread/WARN]: Skipping bad option: key_key.command:key.keyboard.slash
[18:47:24] [Client thread/WARN]: Skipping bad option: key_key.screenshot:key.keyboard.f2
[18:47:24] [Client thread/WARN]: Skipping bad option: key_key.togglePerspective:key.keyboard.f5
[18:47:24] [Client thread/WARN]: Skipping bad option: key_key.smoothCamera:key.keyboard.unknown
[18:47:24] [Client thread/WARN]: Skipping bad option: key_key.fullscreen:key.keyboard.f11
[18:47:24] [Client thread/WARN]: Skipping bad option: key_key.spectatorOutlines:key.keyboard.unknown
[18:47:24] [Client thread/WARN]: Skipping bad option: key_key.hotbar.1:key.keyboard.1
[18:47:24] [Client thread/WARN]: Skipping bad option: key_key.hotbar.2:key.keyboard.2
[18:47:24] [Client thread/WARN]: Skipping bad option: key_key.hotbar.3:key.keyboard.3
[18:47:24] [Client thread/WARN]: Skipping bad option: key_key.hotbar.4:key.keyboard.4
[18:47:24] [Client thread/WARN]: Skipping bad option: key_key.hotbar.5:key.keyboard.5
[18:47:24] [Client thread/WARN]: Skipping bad option: key_key.hotbar.6:key.keyboard.6
[18:47:24] [Client thread/WARN]: Skipping bad option: key_key.hotbar.7:key.keyboard.7
[18:47:24] [Client thread/WARN]: Skipping bad option: key_key.hotbar.8:key.keyboard.8
[18:47:24] [Client thread/WARN]: Skipping bad option: key_key.hotbar.9:key.keyboard.9
[18:47:24] [Client thread/INFO]: LWJGL Version: 2.9.4
```

Comment: Take a look at this https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-127650.